# how to execute testng in mac os command terminal

Tags: java, testng

When i try to execute my testng from windows machine, I'm able to execute mky tests without any issues.

I'm using the command: `java -cp bin;jarslib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`
I'm having all of my jars in jarslib folder inside our project folder.

But when i execute from MAC OS, i'm getting follwoing error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
```

or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
jarslib/bsh-2.0b6.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
jarslib/bsh-2.0b6.jar: line 2: 
                              ?EH: command not found
jarslib/bsh-2.0b6.jar: line 3: command not found
jarslib/bsh-2.0b6.jar: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
jarslib/bsh-2.0b6.jar: line 4:`?EH?Je?^META-INF/MANIFEST.MFm??N1
                                                                 ??Hy?eH.9t?D{C???.)M??ҩoO'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is interpreting your command as 2 commands because of the semi-colon in your classpath. Use colon (:) as the delimiter instead:

```
java -cp bin:jarslib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to explicitly mention that the `;` (semicolon) is the classpath separator on Windows, while it is `:` (colon) on (most) other platforms, including macOS.

Comment: I'm getting output like this:



===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2
===============================================

But the execution is not happening.